# TypeScript SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when using type declarations

Tags: typescript, discord

I'm new to TypeScript, when I try to declare types I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here's the full Error:

```
C:\Users\Irian\Documents\bots\hatsune\src\config.ts:2
    token: String = "No"


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Irian\Documents\bots\hatsune\src\bot.ts:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
```

config.ts:

```
class Config {
    token: String = "No"
    prefix: String = "hat"
};
```

So why is it not working if typescript is for type definitions?

Comment: How is that code executed? The call chain shows there is a lot of module loaders and compilers visited but does this actually *support* TypeScript?

Comment: There's a huge thread on this in github. For me, I had to uninstall and reinstall different packages until I got some versions that actually worked, and it ended up being my test suite (the error occurred when running tests) of mocha and chai not working with my updated version of node, I believe.

Comment: [Github thread](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1846#issuecomment-724479398), in case you are interested

Comment: I believe that you did not compile your TS to JS.